# Number of digits and last digit of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms, exponentiation

How can I find the number of digits and the last digit of the number $$\large{2357^{2357^{.^{.^{.^{2357}}}}}}$$
Basically $2357$ to the power of $2357, 2357$ times.

Comment: Why not start with something simpler, like $$3^{3^{3^3}}$$ and see what difficulties arise there and whether you can surmount them?

Comment: Since you keep elevating to the same power, you may try to set up an inductive formula. But I'd try something simpler first, as suggested by Gerry. Also, for the "last digit" businness, check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43327/evaluate-the-last-digit-of-77777?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to write the number of digits down, because it is larger than the number of particles in the universe.

However, the last two digits are '57'.  You can see that $2357=1 \pmod{4}$, and so the whole exponent reduces to $1 \pmod{4}$.  Since the period of $100$ is four places, it simply amounts to finding what $57^1$ ends in decimal - ie '57'.

Comment: Is it possible to know if it is a prime number?

Comment: 2357 is prime.  Its power is unlikely to be prime, because it is divisible by 2357.

Comment: It's not prime, since 2357 divides it.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: "the period of 100 is four places" --- I don't understand what that means.

Comment: The period of four means that 2357 powers have a period of four places, ie 57, 49, 93, 01.